# pytest finding and not finding modules to test

Tags: python, pytest

I was going to post this question in code review because rather than a solution I wanted for python experts to check my code.
But while preparing the code I found some related issue so I finally decided to ask it here since it is not more just a code check

My question is how does pytest finds modules to test?
Let me explain

**Situation 1**
First I have this code structure

```
|
|-tests
|    |----test_sum.py
|
|--script_to_test.py
```

test_sum.py

```
import script_to_test

def test_sum():
    d=script_to_test.sum(6,5)
    assert d==11
```

script_to_test.py

```
def sum(a,b):
    return a+b
```

If I create a virtual environment and install pytest there, or if I use a conda environment with pytest installed I can do

```
pytest
```

and I will get

```
pytest 
====================================================================== test session starts ======================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.16, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/me/pytestExample
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                

tests/test_sum.py .                                                                                                                                       [100%]

======================================================================= 1 passed in 0.01s =======================================================================
```

**Situation 2**
If I add a file `pytest.ini` in the root

```
[pytest]
python_files = test_*
python_classes = *Tests
python_functions = test_*
```

pytest will not work anymore and I will get

```
 pytest
========================================================= test session starts ==========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.16, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/me/pytestExample, configfile: pytest.ini
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                            

================================================================ ERRORS ================================================================
__________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_sum.py __________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/me/pytestExample/tests/test_sum.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../../.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_sum.py:1: in <module>
    import script_to_test
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script_to_test'
======================================================= short test summary info ========================================================
ERROR tests/test_sum.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================================================== 1 error in 0.07s ===========================================================
```

Now, I can solve this already, but the purpose of this question is to know *why it fails to work* when a `pytest.ini` is added? and why does it work in the first place when that file is not present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default glob patterns for test filename discovery are:

```
["test_*.py", "*_test.py"]
```

This is documented [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery) and you can see it in the pytest source [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/7.2.2/src/_pytest/python.py#L111-L117).

That means that pytest considers your file `script_to_test.py` as a test file itself, since it's matching the second pattern `*_test.py`. If you add a function named `test_something()` inside that `script_to_test.py` file, it will also be called during the test run.

During the test discovery process, pytest will import all the test modules, which makes them available in `sys.modules`. When your test actually runs, the import statement in `test_sum.py` is able to resolve the import because `script_to_test` has already been imported (it's cached in `sys.modules`).  You could add this to the top of `test_sum.py` to verify:

```
import sys
if "script_to_test" in sys.modules:
    print("It's already imported!\n")

...
```

Run with `pytest -s` to show the print output.

```
collecting ...
It's already imported!
collected 1 item

tests/test_sum.py .
```

So, the import resolves because of an *accident* - the code under test is accidentally matching the test filename pattern. If you rename the module to something that's not matching the default discovery patterns, such as `script_to_taste.py`, then the test run will fail. Similarly, when you override the default patterns by adding `python_files = test_*` in `pytest.ini` you're disabling the `*_test.py` pattern and preventing `script_to_test.py` from being imported during the test discovery process.

Comment: Thanks @wim for the excellent answer! I have a following question that I will post in a separate question in the next 15 minutes.  I will appreciate your take on that as well

Comment: @KansaiRobot I've already answered that question from a different user, I will close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

following your structure:

```
from .. import script_to_test

def test_sum():
    d=script_to_test.sum(6,5)
    assert d==11
```

As you are importing from a folder, when you put:

```
import script_to_test
```

this will work for every file you have inside test folder...but your `script_to_test` is not in the same folder...is one level before...so two dots (..) will bring you to the correct level related to this file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you can see, in the first situation it works without `..` It can import `script_to_test` without problems (actually I have a third situation in which it works this way too so I was not looking for a solution, but for an explanation why it does not work with the ini file.

Comment: thanks for reply...curious...I tested both implementation and both is not running :\

Comment: Are you using poetry or some other initialization file? In my case it does not work with `pytest.ini` and also it does not work with poetry's `pyproject.toml` but if I just create a virtual environnment from scratch it works

Comment: not...just pytest

Comment: well...I'll just wait for wim answer and I'll delete my answer...as I was already downvoted

Comment: no need to delete it. It is appreciated!

Comment: Right...I'll let then...tnks

Comment: Relative imports like `from .. import script_to_test` will only work in the context of a package.  The tests are (usually) not part of the package being tested. This answer is wrong and yeah I think you should delete it.